# How did I get part of a unicorn's tear?

Tags: kittens-game

I just noticed that I had 22.288 unicorn tears. The only way that I know of to obtain tears is to sacrifice unicorns. Each sacrifice take 2500 unicorns and yields 1 tear per ziggurat.

So how did I end up with a fractional number of unicorn tears? Can magnetos affect these somehow...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably already noticed that you can purchase upgrades in the "Religion" tab multiple times for some more ivory and unicorn tears.  What you perhaps did not notice, though, was that the cost for each upgrade increases by 15% (multiplicatively) each level.  That increase turns out to make the cost fractional for every level past the first one, which would explain why you have fractional parts of tears left over after upgrading.